# What is the variable that brings up the longer description in VM3?

Tags: joomla-2.5, virtuemart

I want to know the variable that makes the string appear for the longer description in VM3 so I can put it on the admin order confirmation e-mail.

If no one knows can you at least give me the correct file path for the strings so I can find it myself please? (The file that defines strings, not the emails as that's what I'm working on)

Answer (score 2):

Order Confirmation Emails are created from code stored in bunch of files in folder components\com_virtuemart\views\invoice\tmpl\

I'm not sure, but think that you can find variables for product info in file invoice_items.php

Haven't tried for this particular issue, but it is considered best practice not to change original code (which will be overwritten on next VM upgrade), but to create template override in your active template's html folder, and then to edit it.

Good luck.

Comment: I have been editing that file, that's why I wanna know the string variable, it's not on there for the description